# Ghosted for a few minutes by a Suggested Edit?

Tags: support, bug, reviewing

Recently, I expanded the *Review Queue* list and saw a red dot on the *Suggested Edits* queue *(if you don't know, that means that it's not empty)*, so I clicked on it *(naturally)*. But as I was reviewing, I accidentally closed the tab, and when I hurried back to the queue, it was empty.

After a few minutes, after I've tried and failed to locate the post *(as I've neglected to read the title earlier)* to see what the verdict was, when I checked the Suggested Edit again, the suggested edit was back. I saw one *"Community♦ reviewed this..."*, which meant that one more review was needed, so it shouldn't have disappeared from the queue. I completed the review, by the way.

Am I the only one to experience such a ghost review?

Comment: Someone please do correct me if I'm wrong - wouldn't a review by a diamond account automatically approve the edit entirely, since they come with mod privileges?

Comment: @Stiv I don't think it also holds for Community♦ because it's not a moderator: it represents the community [in some sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click of a review without having taken any sort of action, SE will count it as a 'skip'.

This means that the review will disappear from your queue, even though it is still actually there. If you manage to manually find it, then you can still vote.

However, the queue can be quite... buggy. This is probably a small bug, or perhaps the action that the community user took meant that the post was now eligible to reappear in your review queue.

Either way, I wouldn't worry too much, the queue can be a bit odd sometimes and it definitely doesn't like people clicking off a review without taking any action.